# Can anyone tell me what this sentence means?

Tags: meaning

From the Guardian article [Labour reshuffle a ‘move towards the voters’, says Wes Streeting](https://amp.theguardian.com/politics/2021/nov/30/keir-starmers-labour-reshuffle-a-move-towards-the-voters):

> Starmer's office is keen to cut back the number of political advisers on Labour's payroll significantly, with several shadow ministers being asked to *share or manage without.*

Comment: What part of the sentence do you not understand? Have you looked the words up in a reliable dictionary, like [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/)? Is it the sentence structure? Is it the portion at he end in italics?

Answer (score 2):

Up to now, senior Opposition politicians have each had their own political adviser. This is expensive. Some shadow ministers are being asked to EITHER share political advisers with other shadow ministers instead of having one assigned exclusively, OR manage without a political adviser altogether

Answer (score 1):

It means several shadow ministers would have to share or manage without political advisers.